# Error al asociar a un usuario un repositorio de migración

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, migration, oracle-19c

Desde el usuario SYS creo un usuario con la siguiente sentencia:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO REPOSITORIO IDENTIFIED BY REPOSITORIO;
```

Cuando intento asociar a este usuario un repositorio de migración al estar en el paso de "creando disparadores" obtengo el error:

```
Error de SQL en la ejecución del script. Intente suprimir el repositorio antes de crear uno.
```

Ya he intentado crear el usuario desde SYSTEM y obtengo el mismo error, también le he otorgado todos los roles y privilegios disponibles pero sigue apareciendome ese error, tengo una versión 19c de Oracle, espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Pues ahí sólo nos muestras un grant y no la creación del usuario. Igual, creería que faltan permisos. Las respuestas a esta pregunta son de ayuda? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108410/sql-error-on-script-execution-try-deleting-repository-before-creating-repositor

Comment: Al realizar el grant se crea el usuario, pero de igual manera ya intente crearlo con CREATE USER REPOSITORIO IDENTIFIED BY REPOSITORIO DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS; también ya seguí las respuestas del link pero no ha funcionado para mí

Comment: Tienes Oracle 19c... estás corriendo esas sentencias con SYS sobre la CDB o sobre alguna PDB?

Comment: Si es Oracle 19C, ya lo probe con ambas y el error sigue apareciendo, es decir tengo una instancia que no tiene PDB y otra instancia que si tiene PDB, pero en ninguna de las 2 me deja asociar el repositorio

Comment: Qué versión de SQL Developer estás usando? Intenta con una reciente (v19), que en cada referencia a este error, veo que es en versiones relativamente viejas

Comment: Tengo la 19.4 intentare con una versión 20